# Перезапуск службы на удаленном компьютере powrshell

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, powershell

В локальной сети компьютер с ip 192.168.0.146 name  Analytic5.
На моем пк win10 у юзера win7
Пытаюсь перезапустить службу печати:

```
Get-Service -Name Spooler  -ComputerName Analytic5 | Restart-Service
```

Выдается ошибка:

```
Get-Service : Не удается найти службу с именем службы "Spooler".
строка:1 знак:1
+ Get-Service -Name Spooler  -ComputerName Analytic5 | Restart-Service
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Spooler:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
```

Comment: а сервис точно есть ?

Comment: @Senior Automator
не понял Вас

Comment: зайди на удаленный комп и выполни `Get-Service -Name Spooler` и убедись, что сервис с таким именем точно есть

Comment: @Senior Automator
я поменял на ту,которая есть spoolsv.exe но ошибка такая же
`spoolsv.exe`

Comment: но ты так и не ответил что возвращает команда `Get-Service -Name Spooler`, выполненная локально на машине `Analytic5 `

Comment: @ Senior Automator
установлю powershell и отпишусь на удален.пк

Answer (score 3):

**Restart-Service** как и **Start-Service**, как и **Stop-Service** можно использовать только к локальному компьютеру. Соответственно, проходя через канал, объект с описанием службы 'Spooler' применяется командлетом Restart-Service к локальному компьютеру.

В данной ситуации я советую воспользоваться WMI, вот так:

```
$WMI = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'Spooler'" -ComputerName Analytic5 -Credential (Get-Credential)
$WMI.StopService()
$WMI.StartService()
```

Если использование WMI по каким-либо причинам не разрешено, но доступен WinRM, можно воспользоваться командлетом **Invoke-Command**, вот так:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-Service -Name Spooler | Restart-Service} -ComputerName Analytic5 -Credential (Get-Credential)
```